# How to inline a dedicated function in multiple modules in LLVM?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am writing an LLVM Pass. To simplify, all it does is to insert a function call to `foo` at the beginning of every function.

```
void f() {...}  -> void f() {foo(); ...}
```

My first implementation is to add the declaration of `foo` in every module and create a `CallInst` to it in every function. The definition of `foo` will be compiled into a dedicated object file, and linked at the end.

However, I face a problem when I want to the function `foo` to be inlined. I come out with two ideas: definition in hpp, and LTO.

1.
My first idea is to write the definition of `foo` in an hpp file, and all other modules will include it.
To avoid multiple definition, the function `foo` should be a local symbol.

However, it seems that the unused local function definition will be removed, which means that the module given to my pass has nothing about `foo`. (`foo` is not called in the original file, it is called after my pass inserts the corresponding codes).

2.
My second idea is to use LTO to do the inlining in the linking phase. However, the LTO takes too much time.

Are there any methods to solve this inlining problem?

Comment: This is a terrible idea but would a macro solve your problem? Also, what's wrong with an `inline` defined in a hpp file? It wouldn't cause redefinition errors

Comment: thedemons: A C/C++ compiler is not required to include an unused `inline` function in the .bc, and the function is unused at the point where the compiler checks. The pass that uses the function runs later.